# Did I violate some javascript rule?

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple html and javascript.

```
<html>
<body>
   <h1>Test function</h1>
   <p>Hello</p>
   <script>
      function goodbye() {
         document.write ("good bye");
      }   
      goodbye();
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result displays a Hello and good bye string.  I moved the goodbye function to its own file "goodbye.js"  So my first html now looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Test function</h1>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <script src='goodbye.js'>
        goodbye();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if I run the html again, it only displays Hello.  I did not expect that.   What happened ?

Comment: when you include a external js file using script tag. its content should be empty. you need another script block to refer the function goodbye

Comment: Yes, you used `document.write`. It's an unwritten rule that you shouldn't do this.

Comment: 5 people answered the question in the same exact way: add another `<script>` tag. Can somebody merge all of those answers into one?

Comment: @PaulS. Though poor form, `document.write` is not the reason for this not working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) says:

> The script may be defined within the contents of the SCRIPT element **or** in an external file. If the src attribute is not set, user agents must interpret the contents of the element as the script. If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI.

So the correct way to call `goodbye()` is to add one more `script` tag after the first one with `src` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You need two script tags, I believe.  The one with `src` should be empty, as its contents are defined *by* `src` and your inline `goodbye();` is ignored.  Make a second tag without a `src` for the embedded call to `goodbye`.

Answer (score 2):

When you add `src` property to `<script>` tag browser will ignore all contents under it. So you need to add additional `<script>` tag:

```
<script src='goodbye.js'></script>
<script>
    goodbye();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't get to use a script element to download a script and use it as an embedded script.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Test function</h1>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <script src='goodbye.js'></script>
    <script>
      goodbye();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively you could add goodbye(); call to the end of goodbye.js.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have `src` attribute plus text content to a `script` element. If there is a `src` attribute, it will be use, and the text content ignore.

```
<script src='goodbye.js'></script>
<script>goodbye();</script>
```